# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape (1,224,224,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I am doing image classification and I trained a model and saved a model. When I try to predict the model, it shows input error. I am building a classifier using ResNet Architecture and initially declared input_size as **224 x 224**. Now I need to predict the class of the test image.

I converted the image into **224x224 numpy array**. when I try the below code

```
#plot the figure
fig = plt.figure()

for num,data in enumerate(test_data):

    img_num = data[1]
    img_data = data[0]

    y = fig.add_subplot(9,3,num+1)
    orig = img_data
    data = img_data.reshape(1,IMG_SIZ,IMG_SIZ,3)

    #predict the model
    model_out = model.predict_classes([orig])[0]

    if np.argmax(model_out) == 1: str_label='Dog'
    else: str_label='Cat'

    y.imshow(orig,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title(str_label)
    y.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    y.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


plt.show()
plt.savefig('test_labeled.jpg')
```

It shows me the following error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 50176 into shape
>   (1,224,224,3)

in what size I have to reshape the correct dimension?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `data[0]`? Are you trying to resize an image by using `.reshape()`?

Comment: in test_data there are two variables grouped together. data[1] is image-id and data[0] is the image matrix of shape(224x224)

Comment: Seems your input is of size `[224, 224, 1]` instead of `[224, 224, 3]`, so reshape accordingly.

Comment: I changed the dimensions into (224x224x1) but now this error popups ValueError: Error when checking input: expected resnet50_input to have shape (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (224, 224, 1)

Comment: can you check the whole code? I post in the github gist [code](https://github.com/Madhivarman/python/blob/master/resnet_classification.ipynb)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems your input is of size `[224, 224, 1]` instead of `[224, 224, 3]`. Looks like you converting your inputs to `gray scale` in `process_test_data()`

you may need to change:

```
img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZ,IMG_SIZ))
```

to:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZ,IMG_SIZ),3)
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case function was expecting `RGB` image and it has failed cause it was `RGBA` one what automatically means it's got 4 channels instead of 3.
so I've refurbished their function in order to be able to swallow RGBA

```
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    if image.getdata().mode == "RGBA":
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    np_array = np.array(image.getdata())
    reshaped = np_array.reshape((im_height, im_width, 3))
    return reshaped.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: thanks for the insight. it's really helpful to see future possibilities.